# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier:new.mongoose.Schema is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

1. This is my `product.js`,it is saying unidentified identifier, when I make changes to one code another error occurs. I am unable to find the root of error.

   **product.js**

   ```js
   const mongoose = require('mongoose');
   // const dotenv = require('dotenv');

   const productSchema = new.mongoose.Schema({

          name: {
              type: String,
              required: [true, 'Please encter product name'],
              trim: true,
              maxlength: [100, 'Product name cannot exceed 100 characters']
          },
          price: {
              type: Number,
              required: [true, 'Please encter product price'],
              trim: true,
              maxlength: [5, 'Product name cannot exceed 5 characters'],
              default: 0.0
          },
          description: {
              type: String,
              required: [true, 'Please encter product description'],
              trim: true,
          },
          ratings: {
              type: Number,
              default: 0
          },
          images: [{
                  public_id: {
                      type: string,
                      required: true
                  }
              }

          ]
      },

      category: {

          type: String,
          required: [true, 'Please select category for this 
         product'],
          enum: {
              values: [
                  'Electronics',
                  'Cameras',
                  'Laptop',
                  'Accessories',
                  'Headphones',
                  'Food',
                  'Books',
                  'Clothes/Shoes',
                  'Sports',
                  'Outdoor',
                  'Home'
              ],
              message: 'Please select correct category for product'
          }
      },
      seller: {
          type: String,
          required: [true, 'Please enter product seller']
      },
      stock: {
          type: Number,
          required: [true, 'Plese enter product stock'],
          maxlength: [5, 'Product name cannot exceed 5 characters'],
          default: 0
      },
      numberOfReviews: {
          type: Number,
          default: 0
      },
      reviews: [{
              name: String,
              required: true
          },a
          rating: {
              type: Number,
              required: true
          },
          comment: {
              type: String,
              required: true
          }
      ],

      createdAt: {
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now
      }

   )

   module.exports = mongoose.model('product', productSchema);
   ```
2. This is my error:

   > ```
   >     PS D:\PROGRAMMING\2077\SHOPIT> npm run dev
   >     
   >     > shopit@1.0.0 dev D:\PROGRAMMING\2077\SHOPIT
   >     > SET NODE_ENV=DEVELOPMENT& nodemon backend/server
   >     
   >     [nodemon] 2.0.7
   >     [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
   >     [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
   >     [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
   >     [nodemon] starting `node backend/server.js`
   >     D:\PROGRAMMING\2077\SHOPIT\backend\models\product.js:4
   >     const productSchema = new.mongoose.Schema({
   >                               ^^^^^^^^
   >     
   >     SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
   >         at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)    
   >         at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
   >         at Object.Module._extensions..js 
   > (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
   >         at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32) 
   >         at Function.Module._load 
   > (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
   >         at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
   >         at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)     
   >         at Object.<anonymous> 
   >
   > (D:\PROGRAMMING\2077\SHOPIT\backend\controllers\productController.js:1:17)
   >  >         at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
   >  >         at Object.Module._extensions..js 
   > (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
   >  >     [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before 
   > starting...
   > ```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to change your new schema declaration from

`new.mongoose.Schema` to `new mongoose.Schema`